# Assign file data to struct

Tags: matlab, file-io, struct, textscan

I am trying to create a struct called "points" with members ID, X coordinate, & Y coordinate.  What is the simplest way to scan in the data from a file?  I'm using textscan, but it's not doing what I want so far.

```
FILE points.dat
StationA    2.2   4.5
StationB    5.1   6.7
StationC    7.3   3.2


fid = fopen('points.dat');
C = textscan(fid, '%s %f %f');
fclose(fid);

points = struct('id',C{1},'x',C{2},'y',C{3})
```

Checking points(1) returns the following.  All the x & y values are stored in each point.

```
id: 'StationA'
 x: [3x1 double]
 y: [3x1 double]
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
points = struct('id',C{1}, 'x', num2cell(C{2}), 'y', num2cell(C{3}));
```

Comment: There it is.  Thanks.